# PowerShell how to can I append more data to my parsed JSON?

Tags: json, powershell

I want to add something to my parsed JSON using PowerShell version 5. My code:

```
  $file = 'C:\test\data.json'
  $json = Get-Content -Raw $file; 
  $jsonparsed = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json;

  $machineName = [System.Environment]::MachineName;

 $blockcvalue =@"
    {
    "id": "$machineName"
    }
    "@
```

My JSON DATA:-

```
{
  "path": "C:\\test\\Storage",
  "fs": "C:\\test\\fs",
  "serverAddresses": [
    "http://localhost:5000"
  ],
  "serverCertificate": {
    "name": "My",
    "location": "location"
  }
}
```

I want to add some data to my JSON as following:-

```
{
  "path": "C:\\test\\Storage",
  "fs": "C:\\test\\fs",
  "serverAddresses": [
    "http://localhost:5000"
  ],
  "serverCertificate": {
    "name": "My",
    "location": "location"
  },
  "id": "MyComputerName"
}
```

How can I append "id": "MyComputerName" in my JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used `Convertfrom-JSON`, you built a `PSCustomObject` with the properties and values, given by the JSON file. From now on, you don't modify JSON or text, but a PowerShell object.

To add members, to a object you can use `Add-Member`. In your example that would be:

```
Add-Member -InputObject $jsonparsed -MemberType NoteProperty -Name id -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

Now that you modified the object, you might want to have it back to JSON. You can do so by using `Convertto-JSON`.

```
$jsonparsed | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File 'C:\test\newdata.json'
```